# How can I find a function $p_1(\epsilon)$ such that $\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \frac{p_1(\epsilon)}{\epsilon}= e^{a \pi(x) + bx}$?

Tags: probability, limits, exponential-function

I need to find two functions: 
$p_1(\epsilon)$ such that $\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \frac{p_1(\epsilon)}{\epsilon}= e^{a \pi(x) + bx}$ 
and 
$p_2(\epsilon)$ such that $\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \frac{p_2(\epsilon)}{\epsilon}= e^{-a \pi(x) -bx}$ 
where $\epsilon \in [0,1]$, $p_1(\epsilon)$ and $p_2(\epsilon)$ are probabilities and therefore between 0 and 1, $a$ and $b$ are constant and $\pi(x)$ is a linear function of $x$, where $x \in [-1,1]$.

Do they exist? How can I find them? Thank you in advance!

Comment: if you set $p(0,x):=0$ then you want something like $\partial_\epsilon p(0,x)=f(x)$. By example $p(\epsilon,x):=\epsilon f(x)$ works.

Comment: @Masacroso your function can be easily bigger than $1$ for example if f(1)>1. I am not sure the problem is solvable easily for any $\pi(x)$ because $f(x)$ can be as big as you want it to be

Comment: @MaxFt but $p$ are probability functions by assumption, then necessarily $\|f\|\le 1$.

Comment: I might be missing something. I don't get why $||f||<1$. if $p(x,\epsilon)=f(x)g(\epsilon)$ and  $0<g(\epsilon)<0.5$ f could be within $[0,2]$. Especially since f is exponential of something positive $ \forall x \geq 0, \   e^x > 1 $ so $f(x) > 1$

Comment: $$
\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+\epsilon)-f(x)}{\epsilon} = f'(x) = e^{a\pi(x) +b x}\Rightarrow f(x) = \int  e^{a\pi(x) +b x}dx
$$